# capacative vs optical fingerprint sensor

Tags: arduino

I bought this fingerprint sensor (only the fingerprint sensor):
http://www.zjgrow.com/grow-k216r502-fingerprint-recognition-access-control-systemr502-capacitive-fingerprint-sensor-p1957700.html

R502 Capacitive fingerprint sensor

Now I tried to connect it to my arduino uno - unfortunately I only find documentations about how to do it only for the optical fingerprint sensor.

I now found this:
https://www.element14.com/community/community/design-challenges/designforacause/blog/2018/08/16/fingerprint-skeleton-key-capacitive-fingerprint-module-design-for-a-cause-challenge-blog-post-4

I connected it like he did and used the same code except changing my pins to 2,3 as suggested in the example code.

I get: Did not find fingerprint sensor :(

I checked the wiring - it is as it should be ( i also switched RX and TX just for check)

Any good documentation how to connect a capacitive sensor to an arduino uno?

Comment: Do you have the datasheet for the sensor? If not, it will be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the EXACT same code as is posted in the link you provided (without any modifications), your issue may be corrected by commenting line 28 and uncommenting lines 35 and 36. It should look something like this...

```
.
.
.
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>  
  
  
// On Leonardo/Micro or others with hardware serial, use those! #0 is green wire, #1 is white  
// uncomment this line:  
//#define mySerial Serial1  
  
  
// For UNO and others without hardware serial, we must use software serial...  
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)  
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (WHITE wire)  
// comment these two lines if using hardware serial  
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);  
.
.
.
```

Best of luck!

Comment: This worked for me!